# mysqli prepared statements with setting variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to run a query which is creating a pivot table. The query runs fine on its own outside of PHP but I get errors within PHP with `mysqli->prepare()`

> Sql error #: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SET @sql = CONCAT ...

Without (hopefully) going into the particulars of the query, is there something about assigning values to variables (e.g. `SET @sql`) which needs an alternative syntax here to work with `mysqli`? If I remove everything from `SET @sql` down, it no longer chokes on the `prepare`.

```
$q = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN `date` = ''', `date`,
        ''' THEN `close` END) `', `date`, '`')
        ORDER BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`) 
    )
    INTO @sql
    FROM 
    (SELECT symbol, `date`, `close`
        FROM history where `date` IN 
        (SELECT MAX(`date`) as max_date
            FROM history
            WHERE date BETWEEN '1998-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' AND symbol = 'QQQ'
            GROUP BY YEAR(`date`) )
    ) a;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT symbol, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM history 
    GROUP BY symbol');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to run multiple queries in single `prepare` statement.

You need to create seperate prepare statements for each query in different variables.

**Definition**

> Prepares the SQL query, and returns a statement handle to be used for
> further operations on the statement. The query must consist of a
> single SQL statement.

Source:https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: How would I be able to prepare the second statement using the result of the first variable assignment `INTO @sql`. I haven't been able to return the result of the first query using `$stmt->get_result();` Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but I think if you remove `INTO @sql` from first query then you will get its results

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out as well. Thanks.